# Writing gradle plugin with nested extension objects

Tags: plugins, gradle

I am working on a gradle plugin (i dont know groovy, and just started using gradle) that integrates with Asgard (from netflix).  I want my extension object to look like this for the user:

```groovy
asgard {
  url = "http://asgard"
  regions {
    "us-east-1" {
      autoScaling {
        {
          devPhase = "test"
          min = 3
          max = 6
          availabilityZones = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
          ami = "Base AMI 2013-07-11"
          instanceType = "m3.xlarge"
          securityGroups = ["base", "test-application"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or something close to that.  I have been able to get close to this by making autoScaling a List, but when ever i try to get a property from that class it seems to return a dynamic property and never the value.  Here is the below starter plugin:

```groovy
import org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator

class AsgardPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project) {
    project.extensions.create("asgard", AsgardPluginExtension, project)
    project.asgard.extensions.regions = project.container(AsgardRegion) {String name ->
      AsgardRegion region = project.gradle.services.get(Instantiator).newInstance(AsgardRegion, name)
      assert region instanceof ExtensionAware

      region.extensions.add("autoScaling", project.container(AsgardAutoScaling))

      return region
    }


    project.task('displayConfigs') << {
      if(project.asgard.applicationName == null) project.asgard.applicationName = project.name
      println "Asgard URL $project.asgard.url"
      println "Application name $project.asgard.applicationName"
      println "Runs on regions..."
      project.asgard.regions.each() {region ->
        println "\tRegion $region.name"
        println "\tAutoScaling groups..."
        region.autoScaling.each() {asg ->
          println "\t\tdevPhase $asg"
          println "\t\tdevPhase $asg.devPhase"
          println "\t\tdevPhase $asg.get('devPhase')"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class AsgardPluginExtension {
  String url = "http://asgard.sisa.samsung.com"
  String applicationName

  AsgardPluginExtension(Project project) {
    applicationName = project.name
  }
}

class AsgardRegion {
  def String name
  List<AsgardAutoScaling> autoScaling
  AsgardRegion(String name) { this.name = name }
}

class AsgardAutoScaling {
  String devPhase
  int min
  int max
  List<String> availabilityZones
  String ami
  String instanceType
  String sshKey
  List<String> securityGroups
}
```

When I run the task, this is what I see in the logs:

```groovy
$  ./gradlew displayConfigs
:displayConfigs
Asgard URL http://asgard
Application name gradle-asgard-plugin
Runs on regions...
        Region us-east-1
        AutoScaling groups...
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "devPhase" on "AsgardRegion_Decorated@65087be0", value: "test".
Deprecated dynamic property: "min" on "AsgardRegion_Decorated@65087be0", value: "3".
Deprecated dynamic property: "max" on "AsgardRegion_Decorated@65087be0", value: "6".
Deprecated dynamic property: "availabilityZones" on "AsgardRegion_Decorated@65087be0", value: "[us-east-1a, us-east-1...".
Deprecated dynamic property: "ami" on "AsgardRegion_Decorated@65087be0", value: "Base AMI 2013-07-11".
Deprecated dynamic property: "instanceType" on "AsgardRegion_Decorated@65087be0", value: "m3.xlarge".
Deprecated dynamic property: "securityGroups" on "AsgardRegion_Decorated@65087be0", value: "[base, test-application]".
                devPhase
                devPhase test
                devPhase AsgardRegion_Decorated@14860315('devPhase')

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.996 secs
```

Am I going about this all wrong?  If not how can I get the value from the dynamic property (tried get and value, but those don't seem to work).

Thanks for your time reading this.

EDIT based off @peter-niederwieser feedback

Thanks peter-niederwieser for your hints.  After taking your advice and looking at how the closures work I think i have a better understanding of how to set out to do what I wanted to try out.

Here is the syntax of the plugin now:

```groovy
asgard {
  url = "http://asgard"
  regions {
    "us-east-1" {
      autoScaling {
          devPhase = "test"
          min = 3
          max = 6
          availabilityZones = ["a", "b", "c"]
          ami = "Base AMI 2013-07-11"
          instanceType = "m3.xlarge"
          securityGroups = ["base", "test-application"]
      }
      autoScaling {
        devPhase = "stage"
      }
    }

    "us-west-1" {
      autoScaling {
        devPhase = "test"
      }
      autoScaling {
        devPhase = "stage"
      }
    }

  }
}
```

The code to support this can be found here:

```groovy
import org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator

class AsgardPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project) {
    project.extensions.create("asgard", AsgardPluginExtension, project)
    project.asgard.extensions.regions = project.container(AsgardRegion) {String name ->
      AsgardRegion region = project.gradle.services.get(Instantiator).newInstance(AsgardRegion, name, project)
      assert region instanceof ExtensionAware

      return region
    }


    project.task('displayConfigs') << {
      if(project.asgard.applicationName == null) project.asgard.applicationName = project.name
      println "Asgard URL $project.asgard.url"
      println "Application name $project.asgard.applicationName"
      println "Runs on regions..."
      project.asgard.regions.each() {region ->
        println "\tRegion $region.name"
        println "\tAutoScaling groups..."
        region.autoScaling.each() {asg ->
          println "\t\tdevPhase $asg.devPhase"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class AsgardPluginExtension {
  String urlgg
  String applicationName

  AsgardPluginExtension(Project project) {
    applicationName = project.name
  }
}

class AsgardRegion {
  String name
  Project project
  List<AsgardAutoScaling> autoScaling = []

  AsgardRegion(String name, Project project) {
    this.name = name
    this.project = project
  }

  void autoScaling(Closure closure) {
    def asg = new AsgardAutoScaling()
    project.configure(asg, closure)
    autoScaling.add(asg)
  }
}

class AsgardAutoScaling {
  String devPhase
  int min
  int max
  List<String> availabilityZones
  String ami
  String instanceType
  String sshKey
  List<String> securityGroups
}
```

Here is the output I see when I run:

```
$  ./gradlew displayConfigs
:displayConfigs
Asgard URL http://asgard
Application name gradle-asgard-plugin
Runs on regions...
        Region us-east-1
        AutoScaling groups...
                devPhase test
                devPhase stage
        Region us-west-1
        AutoScaling groups...
                devPhase test
                devPhase stage

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.929 secs
```

Answer (score 6):

Some hints:

- There is no need to add an `autoScaling` extension to `region` because the `AsgardRegion` class already has an `autoScaling` property. You just need to initialize that property and perhaps add a `void autoScaling(Closure closure) { project.configure(autoScaling, closure) }` convenience method to support the `autoScaling { ... }` syntax.
- `project.container` creates a `NamedDomainObjectContainer`. The literal syntax for this container is `someName { ... }; otherName { ... }`. There is no "plain list" syntax.
- Your test code sets `devPhase` etc. for the `autoScaling` *container*, which doesn't have these properties. That's why you get the *dynamic properties* warnings. The innermost `{ ... }` is a block (not a closure) and is redundant.

To solve the list problem, either define a `name` property for `AsgardAutoScaling` and use the regular `NamedDomainObjectContainer` literal syntax, or don't use `NamedDomainObjectContainer` and implement your own syntax. For example, you could declare an `autoScaling` method on `AsgardRegion` that accepts a closure, creates an instance of `AsgardAutoScaling`, and adds it to the list.

Comment: Thanks for your hints!  I think I have something working and have a better understanding of how to convert the syntax i want to code.

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but how do you get access to the project object, in order to create the container, within a configure method?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer helped me a lot to resolve my issue. I wanted to add nested extension objects into the `build.gradle` file. Like this

```groovy
family {
   father {
       firstName = "Ivan"
       lastName = "Karamazon"
   }
   children {
       son {
           firstName = "Alesha"
           lastName = "Rakitka"
       }
   }
}
```

Finally, I was able to do that and created the sample project. However, the requirements were slightly different so sharing my experience here. For the details see please SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41491729/3223198 and the Github project https://github.com/andriipanasiuk/family-gradle-plugin