# Adding object instance to gradle plugin extension

Tags: gradle

I have something like the plugin below where I have one outer namespace and within it there is a single 'concrete' instance (`mother`) of an object plus another collection (`children`).

```groovy
family {
  mother {
      firstname = 'John'
      lastname  = 'Cleese'
  }
  children {
      son {
        firstName = 'John'
        lastName  = 'Cleese'
      }
      daughter {
        firstName = 'Jane'
        lastName  = 'Cleese'
      }
  }
}
```

I am able to add the collection object and read the variables based on various examples I've seen but not sure how I add the concrete instance in addition.
How do I define it on the extension object?

Code which shows the issue - I would like to add `mother` as a single instance withing the plugin.

```groovy
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
import org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer
import org.gradle.api.*

class Person
{
  final String name
  String firstName
  String lastName
  Person(String name) { this.name = name }
}

class FamilyExtension {

  final NamedDomainObjectContainer<Person> children
  Person mother
  Person father

  FamilyExtension(children) {
    this.children = children
  }

  def children(Closure closure) {
    children.configure(closure)
  }
}

class FamilyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  void apply(Project project) {
    project.task('sayHello', type: DefaultTask) << { 
      println(
        "Hello ${project.family.children["son"].firstName} " +
        "and hello ${project.family.children["daughter"].firstName} ")
    }

    def children  = project.container(Person)

    project.extensions.create("family", FamilyExtension, children)
  }
}
```

```groovy
apply plugin: FamilyPlugin

family {
  // How do I add support for this?
  // mother {
  //     firstname = 'John'
  //     lastname  = 'Cleese'
  // }
  children {
      son {
        firstName = 'John'
        lastName  = 'Cleese'
      }
      daughter {
        firstName = 'Jane'
        lastName  = 'Cleese'
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what You'd like to achieve. Add support for setting `firstname` and `lastname` on mother or just have on single mother?

Comment: I would like to set the name values on the single mother but more generally like to understand how I have this mix of ObjectContainers and 'plain' objects in the DSL.

Comment: I have also not found any sample projects using both of these or how to set objects on the extension which do not use configure(closure)

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem to yours, but I figured out how to create the "mother" on my case, but not the "children".  The way that I accomplished this is with a nested extension object.

Here is how I did this (mine is in pure java, so you may need to make some changes to do it in Groovy - I'm very new to Groovy, so I'm not sure exactly what needs to be changed):

When you add your extension in the plugin, the class will automatically support the ExtensionAware interface, and thus can have extensions added to it.  In your FamilyExtension constructor add a new extension, casting the class to ExtensionAware first:

```
public FamilyExtension(NamedDomainObjectContainer<Person> children) {
    ((ExtensionAware) this).getExtensions().create("mother",Person.class);
    this.children = children;
}
```

This will only allow a single mother declared exactly as you have.  Note, however, that it won't enforce only a single one, as you can add as many mothers as you want, but any later declarations will have the result of changing the value on that single instance, so there really is only one.  You may also get a null value if the mother had not been declared, so will have to test for that (some demos say that this can happen, but in my own experiments it doesn't seem to).

To get your mother object, just cast your extension to ExtensionAware and retrieve the Person class off from that like you would get the family extension from the project

```
FamilyExtension fext = project.getExtensions().findByType(Person.class)
Person mother = (Person) ((ExtensionAware) fext).getExtensions().findByName("mother")
```

Edit:
An alternative way would be just to define a function on your extension object which accepts a closure and have the closure delegate to a new mother object.  Then you could use a Boolean flag to enforce the requirement of only one mother.

```
private boolean mother_defined = false;
private Person mother_value = null;  // or Person mother = new Person()

public void mother(Closure<?> motherdef) {
    if (mother_defined) {throw new Exception("Only one mother allowed");}
    mother_value = new Person();
    motherdef.setDelegate(mother);
    motherdef.call();
    mother_defined = true;
}
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer. I would have liked it if you would have included the file names for each code block so that it is not a guessing game, however I was able to figure it out eventually. This was the most bizarre part: `((ExtensionAware) this)`. My first inkling was to go for a method taking a Closure.

Answer (score 4):

Well, to add `mother` closure to the `family` you add the following code to the `FamilyExtension` class

```groovy
Person mother(Closure closure) {
   mother = new Person()
   project.configure(mother, closure)
   return mother
}
```

If, at the same time you want to have `children` extension inside family one you add the following code into the `FamilyPlugin.apply` method

```groovy
project.extensions.create("family", FamilyExtension, instantiator, project)
project.family.extensions.create("children", FamilyExtension.Children, project)
```

And then you add

```groovy
void son(Closure closure) {
    Person son = new Person()
    project.configure(son, closure)
    children.add(son)
}
```

to be able to add `son` closure inside the `children` one.

To see the whole project and explanation with more details please visit Github project https://github.com/andriipanasiuk/family-gradle-plugin

Comment: Seems to be a great example for DSL extension dev, but what about implementing this project in Kotlin ? Could we have this done without Closure type that is specific for Groovy ?

Comment: Do you know is it possible to have not predefined names for nested closures? e.g. if I want smth like myPlugin { flavors { name_of_project_module_flavors { /* flavors names here */ }  } }